# Timestamp conversion Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an UDF in pyspark like below to convert string to timestamp

```
@udf(returnType=TimestampType())
def to_timestamp(dt):
    return parse(dt)
```

> TimestampType - from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

I want to convert it to Scala (spark), im trying something like below but it is not picking the arguments

```
def toTimestampFormat(dt: String): TimestampType= {
    return unix_timestamp(dt, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss:SSSSSS").cast(TimestampType)
}
```

am i missing something in this?

Comment: Hi! What Spark version are you using?

Comment: Im using Spark 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a UDF to cast a string into a timestamp, you just have to use the `unix_timestamp` function from Spark SQL by calling the `with_column` method:

```
dataframe.withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss:SSSSSS"))
```

The first argument is the column where the date in string format is located. The second one is the format of that string.

Don't forget to import the `unix_timestamp` function and Spark implicits to use the `$` operator:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp
import spark.implicits._
```

Hope it helps!

### EDIT

If you are convinced that you want to perform this operation in a UDF, then you can't use the `unix_timestamp` inside it, because it must receive a Spark column object, and when you define a UDF, you don't work with column objects, instead, you work with the actual value of that column. This is the reason why 
in your code, `unix_timestamp` *is not picking the arguments*. In addition, the function you create to define a UDF must return a Scala native data type rather than a Spark column data type, so it doesn't make sense to return a `TimestampType` in such function.

To transform an String to timestamp in a UDF, you need a function that takes a String and returns a Long object. In this example, I'm defining the UDF that you want by using the [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) Scala library:

```
  val toTimestampFormat = udf((dt: String) => {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss")
    formatter.parseDateTime(dt).getMillis
  })
```

Finally, this is how you use this UDF:

```
dataframe.withColumn("timestamp", toTimestampFormat(col("date")))
```

### EDIT 2

If you want the column data type to be `TimestampType`, the function inside your UDF must return a `java.sql.Timestamp` object:

```
  val toTimestampFormat = udf((dt: String) => {
    val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss")
    new Timestamp(formatter.parseDateTime(dt).getMillis)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to create it as an UDF because want to use it from pyspark (python).

Comment: This will convert data into Long format isn't? I want to the column datatype to be timestamp and also retain the same data format.

Comment: I have updated my answer again so that the UDF returns a `TimestampType`

Comment: Everything looks fine for me but when I have microseconds  "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss:SSSSSS" Im getting until milliseconds. I checked if there is any option to get micro but it doesnt exists. Is there any way?